# Creating a remote session thru a linksys access point

Tags: networking, ssh, router, remote-desktop

I'm attempting to create a remote session from the internal network to a device that is attached to the WAN interface. Understandably this is a non-contiguous network issue. I have found ways to go from the WAN interface to the internal network and be able to have it forwarded to a specific device. But, that's not what I'm trying to do. Would I have to enable remote management and ssh out?

== edit ==

How I'm remoting is from a windows 7 tower with putty installed out to an ubuntu server running squid.

**question title clarified

Comment: Normally there are no outbound restrictions.  Is this device directly plugged into the WAN port?  Can it ping the WAN IP address?

Comment: The device that I want to remote to is connected to the WAN interface. I double checked with [Administration >> Diagnostics >> ping] and I received a 0% packet loss from it. I feel silly asking this. It really shouldn't be an issue. However. I can't ping it from my windows box

Comment: Ok, and do you have NAT enabled between the LAN and WAN?

Comment: No sir, I do not. Is this mandatory?

Comment: wow, i just asked that

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it all changes since I'm using a linksys access point. I should've been more clear on that.

Comment: NAT isn't mandatory.  Is the default gateway for the ubuntu box the IP of the WAN interface?  The reply packets need to know how to get back.